# AF and manual not working

Tags: lens, tamron

I have Tamron 24-70 with a focussing ring which simply spins without engaging the lens and needless to say doesn't work through the camera either. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably stripped gears. Time to decide whether to repair or replace.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like your lens is broken.

You need to decide if the lens is worth what having a competent technician look at it to see if it is repairable will cost.